# adding checkbox array to kohana orm validate

Tags: php, validation, kohana, kohana-orm

Having trouble adding checkbox values to db via orm

Working for normal fields but not if more than one checkbox is selected on the checkbox questions that allow more than one option

Here is the Form bit

```
<?php echo Form::label('first_name', 'First Name')?><br />
<?php echo Form::input('first_name', $profile->first_name, array('class'=>'inputbox')); ?><br />


<?php echo Form::label('last_name', 'Last Name')?><br />
<?php echo Form::input('last_name', $profile->last_name, array('class'=>'inputbox')); ?><br />

Favorite Genres: 
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Horror"  name="genres[]"  />
<strong>Horror</strong></label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" value="Thriller"  name="genres[]"  />
<strong>Thriller</strong></label><br />
```

Here is the controller bit

```
if ($_POST) {
    if ($profile->values($_POST)->check()) {
        $profile->user_id = $user;
        $profile->save();
    }
}
```

And Here is the Model bit

```
protected $_rules = array(

'first_name' => array(
    'not_empty' => NULL,

),

'last_name' => array(
    'not_empty' => NULL,

),


);
```

Only not working when more than one checkbox is selected, I get this error

> Database_Exception [ 1241 ]: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Not sure best approach for this.. Should I serialize or implode ? Where to do this?

I want to build basic search form in future to search 'like' values using this column.

Comment: Where is the code that actually handles the checkbox data? You only have first and last name in your model...

Comment: NO code yet, that's why I need assistance

Answer (score 1):

This is an `DB` exception, not a `Validation`. You should use ORM relations for this situation:

```
class Model_Profile extends ORM {

   protected $_has_many = array(
       // profile has and belongs to many genres
       'genres'  => array(
            'through' => 'profiles_genres', // pivot table name
       ),
   );
}
```

And then change genres for current profile, like this:

```
try 
{
   $profile->check();
   $profile->save();
   // now replace old genres with a new list
   // clear genres
   $profile->remove('genres');
   foreach($this->request->post('genres') as $genre) 
   {
       $genre = ORM::factory('genre')->where('name', '=', $genre);
       if ($genre->loaded()) 
       {
           $profile->add('genres', $genre);
       }
   }
}
catch (Validate_Exception) 
{
    // wrong input
}
```

Note that not `genres` are separated table, not a `profiles` column. Also you will need a pivot table `profiles_genres` with `profile_id` and `genre_id` columns.

Comment: Thanks 
Not really looking to create new tables considering I will have a dozen or so of these type of multi textbox selections for the user profiles.

Comment: You can store them as a JSON strings. No need for special tables, but you cant use standard DB features like filters.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a genres table and model and create a pivot table for genres and profiles:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `genres` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `genres_profiles` (
  `profile_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `genre_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`profile_id`,`genre_id`),
  KEY `fk_genre_id` (`genre_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Note that you don't need to create ORM model for pivot table.
You can find more in the [official docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships#hasmany-through)

Comment: would rather not make more tables, as I said before this is just one of many checkbox questions. Could you suggest an alternate way. I basically would just implode the array into a string before it gets inserted. Where is best place to do this?